# git credential osxkeychain cannot execute binary file

Tags: github

Hi I am following the **[GitHub guide](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#password-caching)**.
But after executing the `curl` command, I get the following when I run `git credential-osxkeychain`:

```
/usr/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain: 
  /usr/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain: cannot execute binary file
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That could be a right issue, especially if you didn't execute the:

```
chmod u+x git-credential-osxkeychain
```

Note that you need to download that file in a directory which is in your `$PATH` (which should be the case here, with `/usr/bin`).

Try a chmod a bit more large:

```
chmod 775 git-credential-osxkeychain
```